# WS_EX_TRANSPARENT on a firemonkey form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Is it possible to set WS_EX_TRANSPARENT on a firemonkey form? I want my mouse clicks to be passed through the form.

Comment: `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` is Windows specific. Which platforms are you targeting for which you need to support pass through mouse clicks?

Comment: FMX controls have a HitTest property. If the TForm also has that property then I would suggest trying in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `Transparency := True` makes the form transparent and the clicks pass through it.